# How to add a key if it is not present in a JSON Object

Tags: python

I have json Array, I iterating that array and trying to print a particular key and value of json object, but I am getting KeyError.

```
employees = [
{
    "id":"101",
    "name": "abc",
    "mobile":"123"
},
{
    "id": "102",
    "name": "xyz"
}
```

]

```
for employee in employees:
    print employee['mobile']
```

I want to add key 'mobile' in json object where 'mobile' does not exist. Can you please help me, How can I do this in python

Comment: This is not a json array, it is a `list` of `dict` objects...

Comment: look at the `get` method of a python `dict`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mobile = "mobile"
for employee in employees:
    if mobile not in employee:
        employee[mobile]=123999
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second employee object has no attribute 'mobile', so the code raises an error as it should. To avoid that you can use an `if` statement to avoid printing the mobile key if it doesn't exist:

`for employee in employees:
    if 'mobile' in employee:
        print(employee['mobile'])`

You can also add the key to existing objects:

```
for employee in employees:
employee['mobile'] = '123'
print(employee['mobile'])
```

Next time though before asking a question I suggest doing a bit of research as this kind of question has already been asked many times ;)

Comment: In this case mobile value will be 123 for all items that is not correct, I want to add only when it does not exist